# List of characters and foreign characters

Tags: java, special-characters, keycode

I am trying to catch some letters and special characters. I'm using this method:

```
Keyboard keyboard = null;
if (keyboard.isKeyDown(Key.A)) {
}
```

However, I can't figure how to register the question marker for instance (?). The letters I'm in a need of are:

```
! ? Æ Ø Å æ ø å
```

How can I get to use those?

Comment: What classes are you using? Can you give the fully qualified class names?

Comment: Well, it's just the built-in Java classes.
Key.A is the Key class, and Keyboard keyboard is the keyboard class.
The Key class is located in Component.java. It's in the net.java.games package

Comment: You could try registering '/' and 'shift'

Comment: In general keyboard codes for the question mark do not exist, as the key is not on the defined first layer. So go for the key-press event and consider the charCode. An internationalisation issue.

Comment: Can't you get a hold of the byte value of some character and convert it to a String?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no keycode for question mark (?) in java, so not sure there would be any way to catch that. From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html)

> Not all characters have a keycode associated with them. For example, there is no keycode for the 
>   question mark because there is no keyboard for which it appears on the primary layer.

For [exclamation mark](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_EXCLAMATION_MARK), there seems to be the constant `VK_EXCLAMATION_MARK`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
if(event.isShiftDown() && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_1)) {
 //exclamation mark
}
```